# Using power automate to take answers from a microsoft form, and use that to auto populate a task list

Tags: power-automate

What I have so far is a Microsoft form that auto-updates (using power automate) to an app on Microsoft teams called task list.

[image: task list app in teams]

What I want it to do is auto update the other fields in the task from my Form.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried a whole bunch of premade automate flows and scoured the depths of the internet. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Update task details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/planner/#update-task-details) action for this. Make sure you select the id dynamic content field in the Task id field of that action.

Below is an example

[image]